# attempt to change docker data-root fails - why

Tags: docker, debian

I am trying to set my docker storage dir as other than default, something I've done on other machines:

/etc/docker/daemon.json:

```
{
    "data-root": "/mnt/x/y/docker_data"
}
```

where the storage dir looks like

```
jeremyr@snorble:~$ ls -ltr /mnt/x/y
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 11 jeremyr  5001  122 Mar 19 08:14 docker_data
```

with the daemon.json file in place, `sudo systemctl restart docker`  hits `Job for docker.service failed` (without that daemon.json, docker restarts fine and `docker run hello-world` runs fine) . with the daemon.json in place,  `journalctl -xn` shows

```
Mar 25 14:20:33 bolt88 systemd[1]: docker.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Mar 25 14:20:33 bolt88 systemd[1]: Failed to start Docker Application Container Engine.
-- Subject: Unit docker.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit docker.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Mar 25 14:20:33 bolt88 systemd[1]: Unit docker.service entered failed state.
Mar 25 14:20:34 bolt88 sudo[23961]: jeremyr : TTY=pts/18 ; PWD=/home/jeremyr ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/bin/journalctl -xn
Mar 25 14:20:34 bolt88 sudo[23961]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by jeremyr(uid=0)
```

while `systemctl status docker.service` just shows `code=exited, status=1/FAILURE`

and in dmesg I see this:

```
1547:[Mon Mar 25 14:21:41 2019] aufs au_opts_verify:1570:dockerd[20714]: dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch
1548-[Mon Mar 25 14:21:41 2019] device veth34d1dfd entered promiscuous mode
1549-[Mon Mar 25 14:21:41 2019] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): veth34d1dfd: link is not ready
1550-[Mon Mar 25 14:21:41 2019] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): veth34d1dfd: link becomes ready
1551:[Mon Mar 25 14:21:41 2019] docker0: port 1(veth34d1dfd) entered forwarding state
1552:[Mon Mar 25 14:21:41 2019] docker0: port 1(veth34d1dfd) entered forwarding state
1553:[Mon Mar 25 14:21:41 2019] docker0: port 1(veth34d1dfd) entered disabled state
1554-[Mon Mar 25 14:21:41 2019] device veth34d1dfd left promiscuous mode
1555:[Mon Mar 25 14:21:41 2019] docker0: port 1(veth34d1dfd) entered disabled state
1556-[Mon Mar 25 14:21:59 2019] systemd-sysv-generator[20958]: Ignoring creation of an alias umountiscsi.service for itself
```

Docker version 17.05.0-ce, build 89658be, on a debian 8.8 setup .

Does anyone know why docker isn't allowing use of that dir as data-root?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Something is off on the docker_data.

- Solution:

  1. remove the /etc/docker/daemon.json file.
  2. start docker.
  3. copy the /var/lib/docker contents to the path you've put in /etc/docker/daemon.json.
  4. put back the file /etc/docker/daemon.json and restart docker.

Comment: This is not working.

Answer (score 15):

### TD;DR -- worked on Ubuntu 18.04 just before post

follow the instructions:

```sh
sudo systemctl stop docker
sudo rsync -axPS /var/lib/docker/ /mnt/x/y/docker_data #copy all existing data to new location
sudo vi /lib/systemd/system/docker.service # or your favorite text editor
```

in file **docker.service** find one line like this:

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock`

add `--data-root /mnt/x/y/docker_data` to it(on one line):

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --data-root /mnt/x/y/docker_data -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock`

save and quit, then

```sh
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl start docker
docker info | grep "Root Dir"
```

last command should output: `Docker Root Dir: /mnt/x/y/docker_data`

## that's it, should've done here.

---

### The *Too Long* version, if you *Do* want to *Read*:

after some investigating, I found some **outdated** articles, include this one, they mentioned some confident solution, these are typical pages:

- [add `-g` option in **docker.service**](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-move-docker-s-default-var-lib-docker-to-another-directory-on-ubuntu-debian-linux)

  - not working because [`-g` and `--graph` Deprecated In Release: v17.05.0](https://docs.docker.com/engine/deprecated/#-g-and---graph-flags-on-dockerd)
- [add `data-root` in **/etc/docker/daemon.json**](https://blog.adriel.co.nz/2018/01/25/change-docker-data-directory-in-debian-jessie/), the method tried by question author,

  - [not working for some unknown reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55344896/attempt-to-change-docker-data-root-fails-why)

read those solution on about one dozen web pages, got the inspiration:

- [How To Change Docker Data Folder Configuration](https://medium.com/@ibrahimgunduz34/how-to-change-docker-data-folder-configuration-33d372669056)

  - not a very good solution -- not popular, , but the interesting part is below **Update:**:

    **`graph` has been deprecated in `v17.05.0` .You can use `data-root` instead.**

Yeah, `graph` => `data-root`, and the `--graph` is just the long form of `-g`, so I tried  this substitution in solution [add `-g` option in **docker.service**](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-move-docker-s-default-var-lib-docker-to-another-directory-on-ubuntu-debian-linux), and *Ta da ~*

Comment: A real hero.  I know about symlinks, filesystems.  I don't know why I couldn't get any agency over this.  Nothing was working.  My sanity test was `docker images`, the docker info manual test/sanity was good and helpful.  Now finally my root partition isn't full.  Thank you!

Comment: I used  `data-root` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json`. Did not worked, but `docker info` was showing correct path. Tried running `dockerd` and everything was fine. Than I tried starting the service again and it's working. Have no idea. But you can give it a try. I was using single node swarm and saw that in my first run swarm was inactive.

Comment: Interesting comment: "...everything in the second pair of curly braces is being ignored by the daemon, so your solution doesn't work." https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/36598#issuecomment-760978285 Probably, it doesn't work because of bad JSON

Comment: Modifying a system-level file as recommended here is brittle. It could be overwritten by any future system-upgrade or related changes. In the worst case it might even end up with a "split-brain" which is hard - if not impossible - to fix if detected too late. Modifying `/etc/docker/daemon.json` **works** and is the right solution. If something is not working after putting the file in place, something else must be the cause. But modifying a system-level file like this is **not** recommended.

Comment: @exhuma You cannot set options in daemon.json that have already been set on daemon startup as a flag. So using `/etc/docker/daemon.json` has no effect at all for some distros(at least for me using Docker 20.10.12 @Ubuntu 20.04).
And if it would work as described in the Docker docs, people wouldn't search for this SO question.

Comment: For the FYI, when editing a systemd unit file you can do this: `systemctl edit docker.service`. That way it picks your default editor and you don't have to know where the unit file is.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not an expert of docker, but I see "dirperm1 breaks the protection by the permission bits on the lower branch" in your log. And I also see this.
"drwxrwxrwx 11 jeremyr  5001  122 Mar 19 08:14 docker_data"

As my understanding, docker daemon requires the access permission to the directory. Does 5001 mean "docker" group?

However, if you ran the daemon in root permission, then it shouldn't happen.

Comment: the drwrwxrwx  means everyone has read/write perm. to that dir afaik, including docker. I'm not actually sure who 5001 is, it doesnt appear in /etc/passwd or /etc/groups

Answer (score 0):

Check the docker version of your machine by

`docker --version`

I was facing the same issue, and it got solved after upgrading the docker to latest version which is available.

Even the documentation available on docker's official website have not mentioned anything like that.

Once you upgrade docker ,
Restart the docker by

`systemctl restart docker`

The error will be gone, and new changes will start reflecting.